# Understanding webpack.Configuration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, browser

```
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
```

...

```
transforms.webpackConfiguration = (config: webpack.Configuration) => {
    patchWebpackConfig(config, options);
```

While reading some code from an Angular project I stumbled over this code above. What I am curios about is the argument passed to the anonymus function: **webpack.Configuration**. After some research I couldn't find a documentation to this dataype and on my local machine I am not able to "step into" and look at the actual implementation. If you have some information or useful links to this topic I would really appreciate it.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure you know what you are looking at: the right hand side of the `:` in the arrow function argument is the TypeScript type annotation, so the function has only one argument (`config`), which is of the type `webpack.Configuration`.

The types for webpack are maintained in the package `@types/webpack` (state of July 2020). If you want to have a look at them, install them using `npm install @types/webpack` and open `node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts`, you should find the interface `Configuration` there inside the namespace `webpack`.